# Java CombinatoricsUtils.binomialCoefficient() arithmetic error due to large numbers

Tags: java, algorithm, exception, math, bigint

When I try to calculate the combination of large numbers, **e.g. 334 choose 179**, using the Java Apache Math3 `CombinatoricsUtils.binomialCoefficient()` method, I receive an `Exception in thread "main" org.apache.commons.math3.exception.MathArithmeticException: arithmetic exception`

I'm aware that this is due to large numbers (most probably), so I have checked several StackOverflow post to fix it, however without success.

My original code:

```
public static void testCombinations(){
    long test = CombinatoricsUtils.binomialCoefficient(334, 179);
    System.out.println(test);
}
```

I modified it to suit big numbers:

```
public static void testCombinations(){
    BigInteger test = BigInteger.valueOf(CombinatoricsUtils.binomialCoefficient(334, 179));
    System.out.println(test);
}
```

However this doesn't solve the problem. I have checked the value of this example using a standard calculator, with <sup>n</sup>C<sub>r</sub>(334,179), and it is **6.45769855268175x10^98**. I don't need such a long number maybe the beginning of the number, maybe the first 5 or 10 character should be enough. But probably the error generated during the calculation. How should I deal with this issue?

**UPDATE:**

I further modified my code:

> ```
> public static void testCombinations(){
>     int n = 344;
>     int k = 179;
>     double test;
>     test = (long) CombinatoricsUtils.binomialCoefficientDouble(n, k);
>     System.out.println(test);
> }
> ```

However, this only capable of not throwing the exception. The resulting value (**9.223372036854776E18**) is always the same, even with a similarly large number, e.g. 358 choose 179. I assume this value is the maximum of long. So, no solution yet.

Comment: You cannot gain precision from an existing value that is not *already there*, simply by changing the type. If you compute `int x = 1000000000 * 1000000000`, the result will overflow a 32-bit integer, and there is **no calculation you can do with** the resulting `int` that will give you the correct result, for the simple reason that there are **many other values** that would overflow to **the same result**. You can't turn a pile of hamburgers into a cow.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel yes, I know and agree with you. The best would be some mathematical method to preserve the value in order of magnitude. I would be particularly interested to know what others do at such situations. Maybe they transform the input numbers somehow to get a similar result in order of magnitude. Would be great to know.

Comment: Are you looking for the actual mathematical algorithm? Do you need an exact result? If so, exactly how is this a *programming* question, and not a *math* question?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I don't need the exact number, but I have to prepare the code to give similar magnitude of results when using different number pairs. For example, in some situations I have to calculate 3 choose 2, in another situation I have to calculate 3000 choose 20. The magnitude of the result should be considered.

Comment: It sounds like you don't need an exact result. If so, you can write out the binomial as a ratio of factorials and use Stirling's approximation to approximate the factorials. Another approach is to work with the logarithm of the binomial coefficient -- look for a log-gamma function and compute log(binomial) in terms of that, or just compute log(binomial) in terms of a difference of summation over log(something) terms.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I don't know if you're aware of it, but your comments have an antagonistic tone which is not moving the discussion towards a constructive conclusion.

Comment: @Thend Looks like there are methods in that class which return a double instead of an integer and the logarithm of the binomial coefficient. Maybe you can make use of those instead of rolling your own, just a thought.

Comment: @RobertDodier I have tried log(binomial) and seems working :), I will try with my whole code let's see. Thank you for your comments, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple approach that does the calculation while constantly multiplying and dividing to remain (hopefully) in the range of a `double`.

```
public static double binomialApproximation(int n, int m) {
    double k = m;
    if (n - m < m) {
        k = n - m;
    }
    
    double answer = 1.0;
    while (0 < k) {
        answer *= n / k;
        n--;
        k--;
    }
    return answer;
}
```

Note that the maximum `double` is `1.79769313486231570e+308d`.  If you wind up needing bigger numbers than that, then you need to use something like `BigDouble` or `BigDecimal` and be careful about precision, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Since all you need is the magnitude, this might help.

ceiling(log(n)) is the number of digits in n > 1

So the number of digits in n! is about ceiling(log(n) + log(n-1) + ...)

So for the number of digits in choose(n,k):

I'll let r = n-k and assume k >= r.

digits in choose(n, k) ~ ceiling(log(n) + log(n-1) + ... + log(k+1) - log(r) - log(r-1) - ... - log(2))

^^ From n down to k+1 we have numbers that are only in the numerator of choose(n, k). From k down to r+1 we have numbers that are in the denominator once (so cancel with the numerator) and from r on down we have numbers in the denominator twice (so net division).

Here's Ruby implementation:

```
def choose_est(n, k)
  r = n - k
  coefficient = 1.0
  logsum = 0.0
  n.downto(k+1) do |val|
    logsum += Math.log(val, 10)
    coefficient *= val
    coefficient /= 10**(Math.log(coefficient,10).floor)
  end
  r.downto(2) do |val|
    logsum -= Math.log(val, 10)
    coefficient /= val
    coefficient /= 10**(Math.log(coefficient,10).floor)
  end
  coefficient /= 10**(Math.log(coefficient, 10).floor)
  puts "coefficient = #{coefficient}, digits = #{logsum.ceil}, exact = #{choose(n, k)}"
end
```

A few example results:

```
> choose_est(25, 10)
coefficient = 3.2687599999999963, digits = 7, exact = 3268760

> choose_est(334, 179)
coefficient = 6.457698552681728, digits = 99, exact = 645769855268174723155002700285292878609673825371233277541117250760336409272009018138269061870226976

>choose_est(10000, 444)
coefficient = 2.1387299915901736, digits = 788
```

Java code for the same:

```
import java.lang.Math;

public class ChooseEstimator {
    public static void chooseEst(int n, int k) {
        int r = n - k;
        double coefficient = 1.0;
        double logsum = 0.0;
        for (int val = n; val > k; val--) {
            logsum += Math.log10(val);
            coefficient *= val;
            coefficient /= Math.pow(10, Math.floor(Math.log10(coefficient)));
        }
        for (int val = r; val >= 2; val--) {
            logsum -= Math.log10(val);
            coefficient /= val;
            coefficient /= Math.pow(10, Math.floor(Math.log10(coefficient)));
        }
        coefficient /= Math.pow(10, Math.floor(Math.log10(coefficient)));
        System.out.println("coefficient = " + coefficient + ", digits = " + (int)Math.ceil(logsum));
    }

    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        chooseEst(25, 10);
    }
}
```

Comment: This will get you the leading digits and length for values where choose(n, k) is large.

Comment: Hi Dave, why did you use log10, instead of natural log? Does it have any advantage over the natural log? Your approach seems a mix of RobertDodier, very interesting, I like it and give it a try. :)

Comment: It felt more natural! Sorry; forgive me. I used log10 for counting digits (logsum) because we want digits in base 10. I.e., this statement: "ceiling(log(n)) is the number of digits in n > 1" is true for log base 10, not natural log.

Comment: I was just curious, :) thank you very much for your help!